# Stop Comscore bot from visit

Tags: tags, proximity, affiliate, comscore

Actually I getting Bot Fraud for Bot Device while in User Agent it seems comscore crawler.

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; proximic; +https://www.comscore.com/Web-Crawler)

How can I stop making bot visits from Proxy IP's.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use cloudflare you can remove it with this.

```js
(http.user_agent contains "Yandex") 
or (http.user_agent contains "muckrack") 
or (http.user_agent contains "Qwantify") 
or (http.user_agent contains "Sogou") 
or (http.user_agent contains "BUbiNG") 
or (http.user_agent contains "knowledge") 
or (http.user_agent contains "CFNetwork") 
or (http.user_agent contains "Scrapy") 
or (http.user_agent contains "SemrushBot") 
or (http.user_agent contains "AhrefsBot") 
or (http.user_agent contains "Baiduspider") 
or (http.user_agent contains "python-requests") 
or ((http.user_agent contains "crawl") 
or (http.user_agent contains "Crawl") 
or (http.user_agent contains "bot" and not http.user_agent contains "bingbot" and not http.user_agent contains "Google" and not http.user_agent contains "Twitter")
or (http.user_agent contains "Bot" and not http.user_agent contains "Google") 
or (http.user_agent contains "Spider") 
or (http.user_agent contains "spider") 
and not cf.client.bot)
```

configure on cloudflare:

[image: configure on cloudflare]

check block:

[image: check block]